# Передать int в качестве аргумента функции execl

Tags: c++, linux, процесс

С помощью execl вызываю другую программу, которой в качестве аргументов нужно передать int. Но функция требует, чтобы аргументы были типа const char*. И вот преобразовать этот int в const char* у меня не получается. Пробовал так:

```
    const char* intToParam (int param)
    {
            std::string s = std::to_string(param);
            char const *pchar = s.c_str(); 
            return pchar;
    }
```

```
    const char* intToParam2 (int param)
    {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << param;
            const char* rez = ss.str().c_str();
            return rez;
    }
```

В результате передавалась какая-то ерунда. Максимум, которого я добился, это прибавить к int 48 и передать в функцию его адрес:

```
        int foo = 25;
        foo += 48;
        execl("Prog", "Prog", &foo, NULL);
```

Тогда вызываемая программа верно получала число, но если оно получалось больше 70 (70 + 48 = 128), то снова все ломалось, собственно понятно почему.
Есть ли какой-нибудь нормальный способ передать произвольное int-овое значение в вызываемую программу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int foo = 25;
execl("Prog", "Prog", std::to_string(foo).c_str(), NULL);
```

Проблема в ваших функциях `intToParam` в том, что вы берете `c_str()`из локальной переменной, которая не существует после окончания функции.

Comment: Действительно, проглядел. Спасибо, все работает)